# How do I delay start of second animation after the first one is finished (inluding the complete callback function)

Tags: jquery, function, animation

I've got a function that moves a div and another function *complete callback function* that does some other stuff that prepares the div to move again. Therefore I can't write:

```
somefunction(1,2);
somefunction(1,2);
```

because it won't execute the second animation, because it is not ready yet in complete callback function. How do I execute it after the *complete callback function* is finished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the second function as a callback to the first

```
function foo (alpha, beta, callback) {
    var value = alpha + beta;
    callback(value);
}

function bar (someVar) {
    alert(someVar);
}

foo(1,2,bar);

//you can also do this
foo(1,2, function(value){alert(value);});
```

Comment: I've tried it, it does the same, it doesn't wait until complete callback function is finished, it executes right after animation is finished. By the way it's the same function, there isn't a different function, I'm executing the same function.

Comment: Ah sorry, i misunderstood what you were trying to achieve.